# Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service

Tags: salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I'm working with social login on Salesforce Commerce Cloud (SFRA). When I click on the <kbd>Login</kbd> button, I get this error in my login controller:

> For technical reasons, your request could not be handled properly at this time. We apologize for any inconvenience.
>
> Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service is not configured in Business Manager: SocialLoginCartridge.NaverIdLogin.token.Service (app_custom_social_login/cartridge/services/NaverIdLoginService.js#3)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have not followed fully the process described in the Salesforce Commerce Cloud developer documentation for using Web Services. Especially you have not done the first step which is configuring the service profile in the Business Manager.

*To create a web service:*

1. *Configure Web Services in Business Manager*
2. *Code Your Web Service.*
3. *Set Up Logging and Troubleshoot Your Web Service.*
4. *Get the web service ready to go live.*

Please refer to the following documentation article for more details
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/b2c-commerce/guide/b2c-webservices.html